# Как найти минимальное расстояние от заданной точки до ребра фигуры?

Tags: python, python-3.x, математика, геометрия

Я хочу найти минимальное расстояние от заданной точки до ребра фигуры. Каждая фигура описывается точками из списка списков. И вывести эти значения на экран.

Не могу разобраться с индексацией.

```
list = [
    [(132, 0), (565, 234), (543, 103), (320, 129)],
    [(342, 56), (159, 361), (623, 121)]
]

def mouse(self, event):
    self.tutu = [ ]
    ev_x = 100
    ev_y = 200
    for ind, listok in enumerate(list):
        for idx, (x, y) in listok:
            self.tutu.append((ind, idx))

    #  Что то в ней мне не нравится ...
    def line(x, y):
        # Не знаю как передать последовательно все X и Y 
           if abs((x1 - x0) * (ev_y - y0) - (y1 - y0) * (ev_x - x0) /  math.sqrt((x1 - x0) ** 2 + (y1 - y0) ** 2)) > 20:
                continue
           else:
                self.tutu.append((ind, idx))
```

Comment: что обозначают вложенные списки - это координаты вершин различных многоугольников?

Comment: @MaxU да, это вершины фигур.

Comment: Многоугольники замкнутые?

Comment: @MaxU отрисовывает замкнутыми,но добавить еще нужно будет исключение для индекса 0 и max,чтобы и между ними проверял.

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import norm

def get_edges(fig):
    return [[fig[i-1], fig[i]] for i in range(1, len(fig))] \
           + [[fig[-1], fig[0]]]

def dist_edge_to_point(l1, l2, p):
    l1 = np.array(l1)
    l2 = np.array(l2)
    p = np.array(p)    
    return norm(np.cross(l2-l1, l1-p))/norm(l2-l1)

def min_dist_to_edge(p, nodes):
    edges = get_edges(nodes)
    data = [(dist_edge_to_point(l1, l2, p), l1, l2)
            for l1,l2 in edges]
    return min(data)

figures = [
    [(132, 0), (565, 234), (543, 103), (320, 129)],
    [(342, 56), (159, 361), (623, 121)]
]

figures = [[list(p) for p in fig] for fig in figures]

p = (100, 200)

min_dists = [min_dist_to_edge(p, nodes) for nodes in figures]
```

---

результат:

```
[(45.04464802221121, [543, 103], [320, 129]), (133.42589924087187, [342, 56], [159, 361])]
```